# Flutter firestore database returns null

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have following code:

[image: DebugImage]

I use cloud firestore as database

[image: Database]

**UserModel:**

```
class DbUser {
  String id;
  final String authUserID;
  final String userName;
  final List<String>? itemsForSale;
  final List<String>? itemFavourites;
  final List<String>? bids;

  DbUser(
      {this.id = '',
      required this.authUserID,
      required this.userName,
      this.itemsForSale,
      this.itemFavourites,
      this.bids});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'authUserID': authUserID,
        'userName': userName,
        'itemsForSale': itemsForSale,
        'itemFavourites': itemFavourites,
        'bids': bids,
      };

  static DbUser fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DbUser(
        id: json['id'],
        authUserID: json['authUserID'],
        userName: json['userName'],
        itemsForSale: json['itemsForSale'] is Iterable
            ? List.from(json['itemsForSale'])
            : null,
        itemFavourites: json['itemFavourites'] is Iterable
            ? List.from(json['itemFavourites'])
            : null,
        bids: json['bids'] is Iterable ? List.from(json['bids']) : null,
      );
}
```

**Repository class**

```
  final _firestoreDB = FirebaseFirestore.instance;



  Future<DbUser?> getDBUserByDBUserId({required String dbUserID}) async {
    final docUser = _firestoreDB.collection('users').doc(dbUserID);
    final snapshot = await docUser.get();

    if (snapshot.exists) {
      return DbUser.fromJson(snapshot.data()!);
    }

    return null;
  }
```

snapshot.exists returns false.
I do not understand why?
my snapshot returns null but I do not see why it does that, could somebody please help me?

Thank you

Comment: One troubleshooting thing you can do it step through your code line by line, inspecting the vars along the way until you find something unexpected. For example, what does this `.collection('users').doc(dbUserID)` resolve to? Does `dbUserID` exist in that collection? In that document, why does the Field `authUserID` have a different value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmH6U.jpg)

found my problem, there was a space before my Id that had been retreived, I must have accedentally put it there when creating the database...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot of the document you shared, the document ID in the second column is different from the value of `authUserID`  in the third column. So it seems like you added the document by calling `add`, which means that Firestore generates a unique ID for you.

You then create a reference to the document with this code:

```
_firestoreDB.collection('users').doc(dbUserID)
```

But here you are specifying `dbUserID` as the document ID, which doesn't match what you did when you created the document. Firestore now looks for a document with an ID that is the same as the user ID, which doesn't exist and thus gives you a snapshot where `exists` is `false`.

If you want to find the document for the user in your current structure, you can use a query to do so:

```
Future<DbUser?> getDBUserByDBUserId({required String dbUserID}) async {
  final query = _firestoreDB.collection('users').where('authUserID', isEqualTo: dbUserID)

  final snapshot = await query.get();

  if (snapshot.size > 0) {
    return DbUser.fromJson(snapshot.docs[0]!.data()!);
  }

  return null;
}
```

But a better solution might be to actually store the user document under its user ID. You can specify the document ID as shown in the documentation on [setting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document). So here you'd call `.document('theuserid').set(...)` instead of `add(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Indeed firebase autogenerates it's id, so the String id in my model class had to be removed for it to work properly. I have an authUserID because the DbUser (firestore) is linked to my User (authentication) database. The problem was a space before my autogenerated id, stupid mistake on my part ^^'